# No animation when using addPoint()

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to add a category with its own series when clicked on a button. 
See the code; http://jsfiddle.net/3e9PH/

My question; why doesn't the new serie animate like it did when the initial series were loaded?

This is my code:

```
chart.xAxis[0].categories.push("My new category");
chart.series[0].addPoint(['My new category', 5],false);
chart.series[1].addPoint(['My new category', 10],false);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Initial animation is created in a different way than all others. Solution is to set default value = 0, and then update to required one, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3e9PH/1/

Also, use setCategories for xAxis instead of pushing to array value.

Code:

```
$btn.click(function () {

    var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
    categories.push("My new category");
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
    chart.series[0].data[pointIndex].update(['My new category', Math.random() * 10], false);
    chart.series[1].data[pointIndex].update(['My new category', Math.random() * 10], false);
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, pointIndex);
    pointIndex = pointIndex == 9 ? 0 : pointIndex + 1;
});
```